# Database error 1452

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter

I'm working on this project that have foreign keys on two tables. By using a form I'm trying to insert a new record to the database. And there's also an image path in the db and I'm inserting the image path via the form. I'm using codeigniter file upload library. Other fields of the database table get updated when i submit the form even the foreign key field. But the image path is not updating. When I submit the form it shows this error.

```
A Database Error Occurred

Error Number: 1452

Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`bfh`.`products`, CONSTRAINT `category_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`category_id`) REFERENCES `categories` (`id`))

INSERT INTO `products` (`img`) VALUES ('assets/img//sakya.PNG')

Filename: C:/xampp/htdocs/CI-skeleton/system/database/DB_driver.php

Line Number: 691
```

Controller

```
public function add_product()
    {
        $result = 0;
        $cat_id = $this->input->post("category_id");
        $type_id    = $this->input->post("type_id");
        $pname  = $this->input->post("p_name");
        $images = $this->input->post("images");
        $images  = $_FILES['images']['name'];
        $price  = $this->input->post("price");

        $this->load->model("Products_Model");
        $product_id = $this->Products_Model->add_product( $cat_id, $type_id, $pname, $price);

        if ($product_id != 0) {
        $result = $this->Products_Model->add_product_images($images);
        }


        if ($result && $_FILES['images']['name'][0] != "") {
        $this->load->model('Image_Upload');
        $result = $this->Image_Upload->upload("assets/img");
    }

        $this->session->set_flashdata('result', $result);
        redirect('Products');
    }
```

Model

```
public function add_product( $cat_id, $type_id, $pname, $price)
    {
        $result = $this->db->get_where("products", array('name' => $pname));
        if ($result->num_rows() != 0) {
            return 0; // record already exists
        } else {
            $data = array(
                    'category_id' => $cat_id,
                    'type_id' => $type_id,
                    'name' => $pname,
                    'price' => $price
            );

            if( !$this->db->insert('products', $data)) {
                return -1; // error
            }else{
                return $this->db->insert_id();
            }

            return 1; // success
        }
    }

public function add_product_images($images)
{
    $path = "assets/img/";

    foreach ($images as $image) {
        // if no images were given for the item
        if ($image == "") {
            return 1;
        }

        $data = array(
                'img' => $path."/".$image
        );

        if ( ! $this->db->insert('products', $data)) {
            return 0; // if something goes wrong
        }
    }

    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Explain what you trying to do

Comment: I have a tables called products,categories and types tables in the db. product table have foreign keys from categories and types tables. Here I'm trying to insert a new record for the products table. When I submit the form all the other fields except image path field get  updated even it shows an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use "update" query on the behalf of insert in add_product_images().
Because "insert" will add a new record of the product and there is no any category id(Foreign Key) with this that's why shows this error. 
So try to update image.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

you have two variables with the same name and thats the problem.
You need have different variable name.
I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

there are some problems in this script

1. if model you wrote, function add product. if your query failed, returns -1 otherwise return product Id
   but if product was in database it returns 0, then in controller: you check if product_id != 0 then insert images. so you don't care if product didn't exists in database, you failed you insert that in table or not
2. in add_product_images you check if ($image == "") . I don't understand how you get that image array ($images) is empty if this statement is true. you can check if (sizeof($images) == 0) before foreach to check emptiness of image array ($images)